# durandal compose - how to pass data in and out of child viewmodel?

Tags: durandal

Anyone know the right way to pass data back out from a child viewmodel?

My child viewmodel performs and action and then needs to trigger a refresh of things in the parent models.

For example I am doing something like this in my child model:

```
vm.activate = function (params) {
        vm.TaskTypeId = params.TaskTypeId;
        vm.Sections = params.Sections;
        vm.FieldId = params.FieldId;
        vm.Dimensions = params.Dimensions;
```

and calling it like this

```
<div data-bind="sortable: {data: Fields,beforeMove:$root.preOrder,afterMove:$root.saveOrder}">
                        <div class="item"><a data-bind="text:Name,click:function() {$root.edit(Id());}" style="margin-left:20px;"></a>
                            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedFieldId()==Id() -->
                            <!-- ko compose:{model:'tasktype/edittasktype/addedittasktype',activationData:{TaskTypeId:$root.TaskTypeId, Sections:$root.Sections,FieldId:$root.selectedFieldId,Dimensions:$root.Dimensions } } --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this seems to work, but I am wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your child view model yourself (in JS code, as opposed to letting the compose handler do it) then assign it to a property of your parent view model, which you can in turn compose.

```
function Parent() {
    this.child = new Child;
}
return Parent;

...

<!-- ko compose: child --> ...
```

You can then access all child properties from the parent by using the `child` property.

If you need to access the parent properties from the child view model, you can pass a reference to the parent in the constructor of the child (this may or may not be a good idea depending on how coupled you want them to be).

Comment: This is helpful, but I was asking how to access the parent from the child. So, if both modules are singletons, can I use this same approach in the child model to access the parent? Or will knockout do weird things if there are two singleton models that have references to each other bound to the page? Thanks

Comment: If they're singletons it's even simpler;  just `require()` the parent in the child and.. well there you have it.